# How do I save words from a file into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, file, fgets, fgetc

***Some edits:
 int keywords[16];

```
FILE *secretMessage;
secretMessage = fopen("C://Users/anyah/Fall2019/ECE_114/GreatGatsby.txt", "r");

char c;
char temp[100];
char temp2;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

The above is how my variables are declared.
I used atoi() because I couldn't save the word into the array

I need to search through a text file and find the character '_'. Following the underscore is a word that needs to be placed into an array. I need to then print the array of words in the reverse order that they were found in the text file.

I understand how to open a file, create an array, and search for the characters - I am having trouble figuring out how to save the found characters into a string and then into an array.

```
while(1)
{
        c = fgetc(secretMessage);
        if (c == '_')
        {
             while(1)
             {
                temp2 = fgetc(secretMessage);

                if (temp2 == ' ')
                    break;
                else
                    { 
                    temp[j] = temp2;
                    j++; 
                    };
            }
            int words = atoi(temp);
            keywords[i] = words;
            i++;
        }

        if (c==EOF)
        break;
    }
```

I have no errors or warnings when compiling  - this is my current output:

```
0 4200137 0 16 0 4200393 -1 -1 0 4200160 0 9900960 0 50 0 1
```

Comment: How are the various variables declared?

Comment: Where do you put a value into `temp`?

Comment: You don't increment `j`.

Comment: And why do you try to convert string into number (`atoi`)?

Comment: I've updated the post to include variable declaration and why I used atoi()

Comment: `int c;` not `char c;` The function `fgetc` returns `int` not `char` see [fgetc(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html). It is also relevant to whether `if (c==EOF)` tests TRUE.

Comment: atoi() turns an ascii string into an integer, if that string is a set of digits which could represent an integer. If the string doesn't represent an integer, it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
char strings[100][100]; // array of 100 strings, each of them has no more than 99 meaningful characters
while () // outer loop by words
{
    while () // inner loop by characters. Don't forget to check EOF here too!
    {
        strings[i][j] = temp2;
        j++;
    }
    strings[i][j] = 0; // null-terminated string!
    i++;
}
while () // printing loop by words
{
    printf("%s", strings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I understand how to open a file, ..."

No, not really, one fundamental rule of coding is you *"Do not hardcode filenames or use magic-numbers"*. That means you do not want to:

```
secretMessage = fopen("C://Users/anyah/Fall2019/ECE_114/GreatGatsby.txt", "r");
```

Passing arguments to your program is why you have arguments to `main()`, e.g.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

Simply provide the filename to read from as an argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default). To do that you can do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

At this point you have finished opening your file (or are reading from `stdin`) and you have ***validated*** that the file stream is open for reading.

To store multiple words without allocating storage dynamically, you will need to use a 2D array where each row holds a word, and the columns are adequate to hold any word plus the *nul-terminating* character so the array of characters in that row can be treated as a string. The longest *non-medical* word in the Unabridged Dictionary is 29-characters (so a total number of columns of 30 will do, but the next power-of-two of `32` is fine)

Since you do not use *magic-numbers* in your code, `#define` one (or more) constants as needed. You can use a global `enum` to accomplish the same thing. To provide storage for 128 words of 31-characters or less you could do:

```
/* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define ROWS 128    /* max no. of words to read  */
#define COLS 32     /* max no. of chars per-word */
...
    char words[ROWS][COLS] = {""};  /* 2D array to hold words */
```

With your file open and storage declared to hold your words, you now simply read each character with `fgetc` (or read a line at a time with `fgets`) and collect characters until a `'_'`, a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found. To protect your `words` array bounds you make sure you attempt to fill no more than `ROWS` words. For each word, you protect the column bounds by ensuring you read no more than `COL-1` characters (the `-1` to save space for the *nul-terminating* character)

Putting that together and using a couple of counter variables, you could do:

```
    while (row < ROWS) {                /* while rows left in array */
        int c, col = 0;                 /* character c, column counter */
        /* loop over each char in word */
        for (c = fgetc(fp); col < COLS - 1; col++, c = fgetc(fp)) {
            if (c == EOF)               /* if EOF jump out of nested loops */
                goto done;
            if (c == '_' || c == '\n')  /* if char is '_' or '\n', get next */
                break;
            words[row][col] = c;        /* assign char to current word */
        }
        words[row++][col] = 0;          /* nul-terminate, advance word count */
    }
    done:;      /* goto label to jump to */
```

(**note:** the only direct way to jump out of nested loops is to use the old `goto` statement. The only limitation is that you do not attempt to jump out of a function, breaking nested loops is fine)

A complete example could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define ROWS 128    /* max no. of words to read  */
#define COLS 32     /* max no. of chars per-word */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char words[ROWS][COLS] = {""};  /* 2D array to hold words */
    int row = 0, i;                 /* row (word) and loop counter */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (row < ROWS) {                /* while rows left in array */
        int c, col = 0;                 /* character c, column counter */
        /* loop over each char in word */
        for (c = fgetc(fp); col < COLS - 1; col++, c = fgetc(fp)) {
            if (c == EOF)               /* if EOF jump out of nested loops */
                goto done;
            if (c == '_' || c == '\n')  /* if char is '_' or '\n', get next */
                break;
            words[row][col] = c;        /* assign char to current word */
        }
        words[row++][col] = 0;          /* nul-terminate, advance word count */
    }
    done:;      /* goto label to jump to */

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (i = row-1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf ((i != row - 1) > 0 ? " %s" : "%s", words[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

The final loop just outputs the words in reverse order and the *ternary* in the `printf` statement just ensures you don't print a space before the first word output.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/backwardsfleas.txt
cat_lucky_none_has_cat_my_fleas_has_dog_my
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrayrevwords dat/backwardsfleas.txt
my dog has fleas my cat has none lucky cat
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hmm. this seems like overkill for someone trying to figure out a homework problem.

Comment: Well, it's a Hobson's choice on detail. Either you provide a kernel of an answer prompting a number of follow-ups, or you provide an approach that can be applied to any similar problem, along with the why you do it that way. If there were no attempt by the OP, then there would be no overkill. But to address each of the issue individually with the code provided -- you would basically end up in the same place. Overkill -- perhaps, but I always hated teachers that left me just as confused as when I went to see them with the problem to begin with. We'll save the Socratic method for law school.

Comment: @HackSaw -- but thank you for bringing my back, I screwed up the loop limit chopping off the final `"cat"` -- fixed.  lucky is the cat..